# Authenticate Gradle to Azure Artifacts Maven

Tags: java, azure, gradle

I want to authenticate an Azure pipeline to Azure DevOps Artifacts, for which I have the `vstsFeedId` handy. The project is Gradle-based

Locally, it works by creating a personal access token and using the `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id><id>
      <username><username>
      <password><password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url ''
        name ''
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I go online to pipelines, Gradle is unable to fetch dependencies because authentication is not set

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
      > You cannot configure authentication schemes for this repository type if no credentials are provided.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration2'.
      > You cannot configure authentication schemes for this repository type if no credentials are provided.
```

I found that the [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) has an attribute `mavenAuthenticateFeed` that could be helpful, while the [Gradle task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops) has not

How do I authenticate Gradle to my own Azure DevOps Artifacts repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was simple as this.

Use the [MavenAuthenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task

```
      - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
        inputs:
          artifactsFeeds: ''
```